# How to know if the button was clicked with the click or with the enter or space key in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, button, events

When the button was clicked it stay focused so if the enter or space key is pressed it counts as click but I need it to only work with the mouse click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want a button to work on mouse click then you can try using any of the mouse events instead of using the onClick event.

```
<button onMouseDown={(event) => console.log(event)}> Button </button>
```

In your case, you should use the onMouseDown event.
It will only get fired when the mouse is clicked and not on any key press.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an if check to your button function to see what key was pressed and do nothing unless the mouse was used to click it.

```
const onButtonClick = (event) =>{
  
    //32 is for space-bar
    //13 is for enter
    if(event.keyCode === 32){
       
       //leave blank so when space is used to press the button it wont do anything
    
    }else if(event.keyCode === 13){

       //leave blank so when enter is used to press the button it wont do anything

    }else{
      //add what you want to do when button is clicked here
      //this runs when the button is not pressed using enter or space
    }
}
```

On your react button component:

```
<button onClick={ onButtonClick }>My Button</button>
```